# Show normality of a process.

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, brownian-motion, characteristic-functions, gaussian

I am given $(X_t)_{t \geq 0} = e^{-t}B_{e^{2t}}$ where $(B_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ is a standard Brownian Motion. It is also defined $M_t = X_t - X_0 + \int_0^tX_sds$. 
I want to show that $M_t$ is a Gaussian random variable. I started computing the char. function:
$$E[e^{iX_tu - iX_0u + iu\int_0^tX_sds}]$$
I know that the process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is stationary, would this be useful for computing the above expectation? How should I proceed? Any hint on how to compute that integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All linear combinations of $B_t$'s are normally distributed, so the same is true of linear combinations of $X_t$'s. Use Riemann sums to see that $M_t$ is almost sure limit of  sequence of normal random variables which implies that $M_t$ is also normal.

Comment: Let me see whether I got your suggestion: I should approximate the expectation by means of Riemann summation. Than I should find a way to write $X_t$ in terms of Brownian motion increments, in that way I have independence of Gaussian R.V. and I can conclude that their sum is Gaussian. Is this what I should do? Have I understood correctly your hint?

Comment: You first show that all linear combinations of $B_t$'s are normal using the fact that BM has independent increments. Once you have done this there is no need for independence. All linear combinations of $X_t$'s are normal etc.  @YodaAndFriends

Comment: I am sorry but I am bit confused. How is it possible that $$M_t = X_t - X_0 + \int_0^tX_sds$$ is normal knowing that all linear combination of BM are normally distributed? From what I have I could have $X_t - X_0$ as a Gaussian r.v. but what about $ X_t - X_0 + \int_0^tX_sds$?

Comment: It is the limit (almost sure, hence in distribution) of a sequence of linear combinations of $B_t$'s. @YodaAndFriends

Comment: Maybe I got it: I write the integral in term of Riemann summation. Once done that, I then have inside the limit only linear combination of $X_i$s so I can claim that it is Gaussian, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @YodaAndFriends

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!